# Accessing Cypress results outside of the application to display on a Webpage

Tags: cypress

Scope: I am trying to make a website (hub) that displays the test results of other websites in a table like format. For Example:

Google.com - 42 tests - 41 passed.
Or Ebay.com - 50 tests - 50 passed.
Then for each website have a green or red if all the tests pass.

I have been looking for a way to **access Cypress results** like you would access an API to get data from it to be displayed. Is there already a Cypress function like this, that enables *access to test results **outside of the application***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in running via the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#Results), specifically

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress
  .run({
    // the path is relative to the current working directory
    spec: './cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js',
  })
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
  })
```

Results - Stats section

```js
{
  ...
    "stats": {
      "suites": 1,
      "tests": 1,
      "passes": 0,
      "pending": 0,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failures": 1,
      "startedAt": "2020-08-05T08:38:37.589Z",
      "endedAt": "2018-07-11T17:53:35.675Z",
      "duration": 1171
    },

}
```

or per test details

```js
"tests": [{
  "title": [ "test" ],
  "state": "failed",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reporter to customize what the output of the report looks like, as well as several other things, including a destination output for the results. Check out Cypress's documentation on reporters for more information.

[Cypress's Reporter Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Custom-reporter)

Comment: That gives you some resources like videos and html. Can it also just supply json for data approach?

Comment: Mochawesome (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome) generates a json file that you can interpret as you see fit. There are probably many other reporters that generate similar files.